# Cant get type TEXT from MSSQL database PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a MSSQL Database which i use to get data about products. I have been using it to get lots of different data and it works absolutely fine. Up until me trying to add in 'dbo.Stock.NOTES'

It seems that works fine with VARCHAR and Decimal.. but for whatever reason Text does not work.

dbo.Stock.ITEMNO = VARCHAR;

dbo.Stock.PRICE = DECIMAL;

dbo.Stock.NOTES = TEXT

Below code prints out nothing, if i remove dbo.Stock.NOTES from the query it will print out correctly.

```
<?php
$connect = odbc_connect("SERVERname", "username", "password"); 

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 dbo.Stock.ITEMNO, dbo.Stock.PRICE, dbo.Stock.NOTES FROM 
dbo.Stock WHERE dbo.Stock.ITEMNO = 'FUE-GAS-0001'";

$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query); 

while(odbc_fetch_row($result)) {        

$notesmemodesc = odbc_result($result, "NOTES");
$ds = odbc_result($result, "PRICE");
}

...

echo $notesmemodesc;
echo $ds;

...

?>
```

Its like php is erroring at the point it sees dbo.Stock.NOTES and stopping itself from continuing executing the code.

It seems as though it does not like dealing with type "text" is there anything i can do to the code to accept text type? I cant understand why its not okay with it.

P.s. I cannot change the type of TEXT unfortunately

[image: Database Fields]

Comment: What if you convert it in your select?

Comment: Out of Interest, why can you not change the data type? `text` is a deprecated data type.

Comment: A notes field with 2gb seems a little excessive. You could store like 1000 copies of war and peace in that much space.

Comment: Its not my database to change unfortunately just use; otherwise i would CAST(dbo.Stock.NOTES as CHAR(10)) Is what i've just tried doing and altho it stops the erroring as such it still does not show the data

Comment: `char(10)`? So the length of `notes` is only 10 characters? That certainly seems like a massive waste of the `text` datatype, as `varchar` has existed for a very long time on SQL Server. Personally, I would suggest converting it to `varchar(MAX)` though, as that's the recommended replacement datatype; unless the value of `notes` really will have exactly 10 characters.

Comment: That was just a test.. it will probably store about a couple hundred characters something along those lines

Comment: Finally got there :) CAST(dbo.Stock.NOTES as varchar(MAX)) AS 'notes'. Thank you very much for your help. Apologies about the database.. i do wish i could edit it :L